# Markers and polyline loaded from .xml

Tags: xml, google-maps, polyline

I'm in the process of updating my Google Map code from API v2 to v3.

I am attempting to pull both marker and polyline information from an .xml file and display,

I cannot seem to get both markers and polylines to disply correctly on the same map.

I have 2 examples:

This page correctly dislpays the marker infomation:
http://www.frg.org/track_pefa1_all_combined_API_v3_new2.htm

.. and this page correctly displays the polylines but only displays a single marker:
http://www.frg.org/track_pefa1_all_combined_API_v3_new2_with_poly.htm

I am using the same .xml file for both:

I'm just getting my arms around the v3 API ....

Does anyone see any obvious issues or problems in my cut and pasted code?

Comment: Take a look at the look at the loop where you create the markers: Inside the loop is another loop where you create the polyline, where you use the same variable-name for the iteration(i). Use separate loops for markers and polyline(s)

Comment: Thx Dr. Molle ... I actually changed the variable-name for the iteration .... didn't seem to have any influance ... I'm fairly new to v3 ... how would I go about using a seperate loops for each sequence of evvents?

Comment: FYI ... I was able to correct the problem by moving the create markers statement further up the code ..undoubtly using a seperate loop? as Dr.Molle suggested.

see new exanple:
http://www.frg.org/track_pefa1_all_combined_API_v3_new2a_with_poly.htm